# To allow only one numeric value in text box based on regular expression in AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'm using `ng-pattern` :

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern-restrict="/^[4]*$/" required only-digits>
```

Please let me know what to do that it does not accept any other numbers except 4. I am using directive for digits that is only-digits.

Comment: Do you mean `/^4$/` ?  Why not check for 4 in the code?

Comment: Or use `/^4+$/` for 1 or more times a 4

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** SORRY WRONG ANGULAR VERSION - but if you can transform this to angularjs it will be work!

You can use `(input)` event in you HTML input element

```
<input type="number" (input)="check($event)">
```

Than in your ts you cehck value of input

```
  check(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (+event.data !== 4) {
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern which you are mentioned is not a valid regex pattern. Instead of that try to use this `/^([4]){1}?$/` Hope you will get it.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern-restrict="/^([4]){1}?$/" required only-digits>
```

Comment: but using it validation msg is not working     <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below restrict pattern :

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern-restrict="^[4]{1}?$" required only-digits>
```

And below validation message :

```html
<div ng-messages="myForm.price_field.$error">
    <span ng-message="pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @hastaDhana how to give validation msg by using this  <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>